# C# Dictionary: Java HashMap.compute() equivalent in C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Java's `HashMap.compute()` method is very powerful, in that it can:

1. add a `(key, value)` pair, if `key` was not previously present
2. update `value` through a lambda (via its return), if `key` was previously present
3. remove `key` from the hashmap, if the supplied lambda returns `null` - user doesn't need to do `HashMap.remove(key)` (which is one extra hashmap lookup)

C++'s `unordered_map` relies on the `iterator` returned from the `find` method, and uses `erase(iterator)` to avoid extra lookup

Rust's `HashMap` provides the `Entry` API, which uses the `Entry::remove` method to delete the entry without extra lookup

However, I don't seem to find similar facility in C#'s `Dictionary` API - could anyone shed some light on the design of C#'s `Dictionary` API?

Comment: Sounds like you want `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: `AddOrUpdate`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=net-6.0#system-collections-concurrent-concurrentdictionary-2-addorupdate(-0-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-1-1)))

Comment: I actually checked that the closest counterpart of Java's `[Concurrent]HashMap.compute` in C# is `ConcurrentDictionary`'s `AddOrUpdate` method - however, per point 3 (above), I don't see a way that the `updateValueFactory` can indicate (`compute` returning `null`) that the Dictionary entry needs to be removed _inline_

Comment: C# is not ment to replace java. so it is not strange not all methods can find equivalents. however you can easily implement your own extension methods.

Comment: @LeiYang well, it doesn't seem possible to me to implement such an extension method as a counterpart to `compute`, in that the specific behavior (remove in place) requires accessing private fields of `Dictionary` (possibly holding some write lock) - sure - on the API level I can achieve the same effect, but the runtime cost would be different - especially when concurrency is concerned - `ConcurrentHashMap.compute` (that actually does remove when certain condition met) would behave inconsistently with `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate` and then `Remove` (see the differences?)